# XPath translate() function and (de)composed Unicode characters

Tags: xpath, xslt

Take following XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate('abc', 'éabc', 'eabc')"/>  <!--0x65CC81-->
        <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="translate('abc', 'éabc', 'eabc')"/>  <!--0xC3A9-->
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Running this with Saxon 10 returns:

```
bc
abc
```

The first invocation of the translate function uses the decomposed form of é (U+0065 and U+0301), while the second uses U+00E9. It seems they are not treated equally. Is this to be expected? And is this behavior specified somewhere?

Answer (score 5):

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#character-terminology §1.7.1, where it is stated:

> Unless explicitly stated, the xs:string values returned by the
> functions in this document are not normalized in the sense of
> [Character Model for the World Wide Web 1.0: Fundamentals].

So the translate() function works on Unicode codepoints as input, and produces Unicode codepoints as output, and isn't concerned about whether those codepoints represent composed or decomposed characters. If you want normalization, you have to invoke it explicitly using the `normalize-unicode()` function.

(The quote above is a little bit ambiguous for my taste. By "are not normalized" it means "no action is taken to normalize the strings", it doesn't mean "the strings will not be in normalized form".)

Answer (score 2):

I think the result is correct, what happens is that you have e.g. `translate('abc', 'éabc', 'eabc')` where the `é` is two characters in the second argument so the `a` in the second argument value is at the third position and is replace by the third position `b` of the third argument and the `b` is at the fourth position and is replaced by the fourth position `c` and the `c` doesn't have any replacement so it is replaced by the empty string/it is removed.

I guess you can do e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="translate('abc', normalize-unicode('éabc', 'NFC'), 'eabc')"/` to avoid the problem.